# Web Performance Testing

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I am looking for software/app that is advanced for testing web applications. I need to be able to report on speeds, bottlenecks, server responses, and more. The one big part of the testing tool is that I need to be able to report on the load times and response times because we have a proxy in the middle that we think is causing a bottleneck between the app and the server. Windows software or Mac app would be appreciated to know about.

Comment: You can try http://webpagetest.org

Comment: Are you able to get an idea whether or not the proxy is the cause of a bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've heard of [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/), but its a great tool for testing your application end-to-end. It gives you complete performance visibility throughout your application. Easy to install and quick to setup.

Other than that, if you are just looking at profiling your front end performance, there are some great free tools such as [WebPageTest](http://webpagetest.org/) and [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). I'm also a big fan of the [Google Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) for finding front-end bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Visual Studio 2013 for the same purpose. In VS, you can create several  Web Performance Tests and then using these tests you can create a Load Test. I have used these Load Tests to find deadlocks, internal server errors etc. It gives you a details analysis in terms of average time for each request, which requests failed etc. And like all other Microsoft products, VS is easy to use and a lot of help is available online.